# Node gives strange error

Tags: baking, node, baking-node

While checking my node, I saw this error appearing. Baking ops are working so not sure if this is anything to worry about but wanted to ask around to see what this could mean. Anyone?

```
Apr 10 20:40:35 - p2p.io-scheduler: Unexpected error in connection (pop: 622664, io_scheduler(read)):

Apr 10 20:40:35 - p2p.io-scheduler: Error:

Apr 10 20:40:35 - p2p.io-scheduler:   Unix error in read: Invalid argument

Apr 10 20:40:35 - p2p.io-scheduler:
```